# On the A320, is it wrong to retard at 50ft or earlier?

Tags: landing, airbus-a320

The A320 FCTM explains that the flight crew can rapidly retard all thrust levers to IDLE either earlier or later than the 20 ft.

Is it wrong to retard at 50ft or earlier?

Comment: Can you quote the relevant section from your FCTM. The one I have doesn't say that. Mine says "At 20 ft, the ”RETARD” auto call-out reminds the pilot to retard thrust levers. It is a
reminder rather than an order. The pilot will retard the thrust levers when best
adapted e.g. if high and fast on the final path the pilot will retard earlier."

Answer (score 7):

This is a non-Airbus specific answer. Depends on the airplane and how draggy it is in the landing configuration. If the plane has large double slotted flaps and leading edge slats, the plane decelerates quite rapidly with no thrust on, and hard landings result if this isn't managed carefully.

Generally you go by the SOP created by the manufacturer, that was developed in flight test and was briefed in training.

There are two considerations:

You must have the thrust at idle at touchdown, because TLA, trust lever angle, is normally one of the arming conditions for the lift dumpers, with Weight on wheels, WOW, being another arming condition. WOW = yes when the wheels are on the ground is typically maintained in the lift dumper logic for some seconds even if the signal is lost, to prevent the plane from ballooning back in the air if the gear rebounds enough to lose the proximity sensor squat signals.

If you touch down with power on, you'll have WOW satisfied, but not IDLE. The lift dumpers won't extend.  You will likely skip or bounce. As you do so, in your surprise you may yank the thrust to idle.  All of a sudden you are 20 ft in the air, both IDLE and WOW are satisfied (because WOW isn't immediately removed when the wheels left the ground), and the lift dumpers come out while still in the air. I know of a CRJ200 where this happened and it came down hard enough to collapse one of the main gears.

The other consideration, at the other end of the landing flare phase, is how you handle the thrust reduction, which is a function of the airplane's characteristics and the actual energy state, your speed relative to Vref. With slatted airplanes that slow down quickly when thrust is removed, you want to leave the thrust on late, down to 20-30 ft, or if you remove it higher, you feather it off gradually, making sure you're at IDLE by 20 ft. If you're fast, you may move those numbers up to compensate for the excess energy.

Om an airplane with a clean leading edge, no LE slats or flaps, there is way less drag and less deceleration when going to idle and you can get away with going to idle quite a ways out, 50ft, or a little higher if you are at Vref+.

Comment: On the Airbus, the idea behind "rapidly retard all thrust levers to IDLE" is to let the FADEC handle the smooth thrust reduction for you. On a normal flare coming from a stabilized approach, doing this at 20 ft RA will exactly give you idle thrust at touchdown. But as you said, when coming in faster, you may have to do it earlier. 50 ft seems quite early to me though (except maybe for an A318 on a steep approach like London City).

Comment: Interesting thanks. On the CRJ200 and Challenger biz jets, all slatless, you go to all the way to idle normally at 50ft, and it just coasts forever if you get carried away with trying to tease it on gently.  With the trailing link gear and wide energy margins, you can sometimes achieve touchdowns so gentle you only sense the wheel spin vibration. They have an odd nose down approach attitude, but are actually extremely forgiving and easy airplanes to land smoothly. The slatted 7/9/1000s are the opposite, where thrust management in the landing is critical.